# How to return an Object in WCF Web Service?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I have a WCF Service which returns an Object-I. The Object-I is an collection of List,String X,List. my WCF service runs without any error and returns it but when i call this in my silverlight application, i can't read this object-I. 
Please Help Me

```
//WCF Service Interface
     [ServiceContract]
        public interface IUserConfiguration
        {
            [OperationContract]
            userlistresponse GetUser();
        }

     [DataContract]
        public class userlist
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string UserID { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Password { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string User_Type { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Salutation { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string First_Name { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Middle_Name { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Last_Name { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int User_Level { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Address { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string City { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string State { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Pincode { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Landmark { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Landline1 { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Landline2 { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Landline3 { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Mobile { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Email { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Status { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Token { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class ErrorManager
        {
            public string Error_ID { get; set; }
            public string Field { get; set; }
        }       

        [DataContract]
        public class userlistresponse
        { 
            public List<userlist> usersdetails { get; set; }
            public bool Flag { get; set; }
            public List<ErrorManager> Error { get; set; }
        }

//WCF Service Implementation
 public userlistresponse GetUser() 
        {
            userlistresponse ErrorUser = new userlistresponse();
            try
            {
                    DALUsersDetails DUD = new DALUsersDetails();
                    return DUD.GetUserDetails();                
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                ErrorUser.Error.Add(new ErrorManager {Error_ID = "SUR0000",Field = Ex.Message.ToString()});
                ErrorUser.Flag = false;
            }
            return ErrorUser;
        }
//DATA ACCESS LAYER Just Returns a List From DataBase
```

Everything works fine here.and the WCF Service can be called in Silverlight application and can use the method.

```
//Silverlight Application

 public Searchuser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UserConfigurationClient UserClient = new UserConfigurationClient();                        
            UserClient.GetUserCompleted += new EventHandler<GetUserCompletedEventArgs>(UserClient_GetUserCompleted);
            UserClient.GetUserAsync();
                   }
             void UserClient_GetUserCompleted(object sender, Proto.UserReference.GetUserCompletedEventArgs e) 
        {
            if (e.Result != null)
            {
                Proto.UserReference.userlistresponse user = new userlistresponse();                
                user = e.Result;//Its Just Returns a string.
                if(user.flag == false)

//Here is the Problem- The Object User[userlistresponse] does not shows or exposes the member inside that object.


             {
                           .......................//some code 
             }


            }
        }
```

[image: User does not shows or exposes the member in userlistresponse object]

Comment: Hmmm... show us some code, that way we don't have to play guessing games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `[DataContract]` for the class you should iclude `[DataMember]` attribute for all properties which you don't want to skip be transfered.